# She has been diagnosed vs she was diagnosed

Tags: present-perfect

What is the difference between *she has been diagnosed with cancer* vs *she was diagnosed with cancer*

Comment: She has been seen at the market.  [past present perfect passive]. She was seen at the market [present passive simple past].

Comment: Do any of these search results answer the question https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22has+been%22+was